# Strict aliasing rule, false positive or false negative?

Tags: c, gcc-warning, strict-aliasing

I have a problem with strict aliasing in C. I'm using GCC 4.7.1.
Example 1:
When compiling this code with -fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing=3 I get "warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t a[4] = {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67};
    uint32_t b;

    b = *(uint32_t *)a;

    printf("%x\n", b);

    return(0);
}
```

Example 2:
This code gives no warning with -fstrict-aliasing and -Wstrict-aliasing=3 or -Wstrict-aliasing=2 or -Wstrict-aliasing=1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t a[4] = {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67};
    uint32_t b;
    void *p;

    p = a;
    b = *(uint32_t *)p;

    printf("%x\n", b);

    return(0);
}
```

Both examples work correctly.
Using union is also undefined behavior and using memcpy() is too slow in my case.
So, is the first example safe (false positive) or second example is also unsafe (false negative) or ...?
Thanks.

Comment: Using unions for type-punning is explicitly allowed by C99 TC3 footnote 82.

Comment: Aliasing is not your problem here, alignment is. There is no guaratee that an array of `uint8_t` aka `unsigned char` is aligned such that you can read it through a pointer to `uint32_t`. Don't do that, you are heading for trouble. (The other way round is ok.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to manufacture a `uint32_t` from 4 `uint8_t`, then do just that: **manufacture** it. Don't try to pull one from something that isn't one by pointer casts. The code you presented  will vary in results depending on whether you're platform is little or big endian, not to mention its just plain wrong.

They're *both* bad. Both samples provided are unsafe no matter what. data alignment requirements are bypassed with such casts. If anything you're casting 'to' requires potentially more restrictive alignment than anything you're casting 'from', you inviting a bus-error. Heed the initial warning. intermediate pointer-to-void simply masks the problem (as it does for most problems).

You want to *know* what byte is going "where" when you build that `uin32_t`.

```
uint8_t a[4] = {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67};
uint32_t b = ((uint32_t)a[0] << 24) |
             ((uint32_t)a[1] << 16) |
             ((uint32_t)a[2] << 8) |
             (uint32_t)a[3];
```

This will *always* put the a[0] byte in the high-byte of the target 32bit unsigned, a[1] in the next byte, etc, regardless of endian'ness. `b` will *always* be `0x01234567`.

Comment: I would use that only when endian is "correct", but I'm woried about strict aliasing.

Comment: No, this is not the way to manufacture an `uint32_t`, it is undefined behavior because of alignment issues. It is never a good idea to cast to a type that might have a more restrictive alignment. The way to manufacture an `uint32_t` is the other way round, create a `uint32_t` and access its bytes through `unsigned char`.

Comment: @JensGustedt Where this by *reference* I would concur, but the cast-promotion is not done by reference; it is done by value. I'm always willing to see a different side, however, so if you can cite a specific example where value-promotion like the above can (or even better, *does*) cause an alignment issue I'm very interested. Likewise, if there is something above that is specifically in violation of the standard (and thus UB) please note which subsection of the standard it violates.  I've covered C99 6.3 and am aware of nothing that this violates, so if there is something else please share.

Comment: @JensGustedt The guys in chat suggested my phrasing in the first sentence was wrong, and that perhaps you thought I was agreeing with the OP on casting through an unsafe alias to get the uint32_t he was seeking. I was *not* suggesting his code was correct. Rather the exact opposite, so if there was confusion on that half I've slightly modded the initial sentence to make more clear the assessment. That said, if there is a UB problem the answer I'm definitely interested in knowing.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes it is less ambigouous now, good. Still I don't think that you answer the question (but the OP does think so :). There are ways to obtain what the OP wants to achieve (view the bytes in memory order as integers). Only what he posted in his question is not the right answer, either.

Comment: @JensGustedt I just wanted to know, if it's safe.

Comment: @JensGustedt The safety question was actually answered better in a comment, that I've since moved to the answer itself. hopefully that covers the base the OP was looking to address (pun intended).

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the second example is also unsafe - it's just the case there that the compiler is not smart enough to find out that `p` and `a` actually point to the same (1-byte-aligned) location, and since `void *` cannot be aligned (by definition - what would be `sizeof(void)`?), it doesn't issue a warning.

Comment: No, I think casting to `void*` tells the compiler not to expect anything about that pointer, so from a POV of aliasing this is ok. A much bigger problem is alignment. This is what makes the behavior undefined, here.

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes, I'm not telling anything else (at least I hope it's clear what I mean).

Comment: was not so clear to me. and in fact the compiler *must* be smart enough to see that he can't assume anything about `*p`.

Comment: @JensGustedt yes, that's what I mean by "void * cannot be aligned".

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you are accessing your array elements (type `uint8_t`) by another type (`uint32_t`) which is not the signed variant of the original type nor is a character type.

C says you have to access an object by its own type or a signed variant or by a character type otherwise you are violating aliasing rules.